# Problems after adding has_many: and belongs_to:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I had previously created the following model without the has_many: and belongs_to: properties. They worked perfectly before, but not after adding the has_many, and belongs_to, it is not working. I have a joint table and am then trying to associate this with a user through has_many: and belong_to: as listed bellow.

Here is the belongs to for classroom:

```
belongs_to :user

belongs_to :first
belongs_to :second
belongs_to :third
```

When I was previously creating objects through

```
attributes = user_params
@user = User.find_by_id(attributes[:user_id].to_i)
attributes = classroom_params
@classroom = @user.classroom.where(:first_id => attributes[:first].to_i,
                                :second_id => attributes[:second].to_i,
                                :third_id => attributes[:third].to_i).first_or_create
```

After this didn't work, I tried the following:

```
@classroom = @user.classrooms.create(:first_id => attributes[:first].to_i,
                                :second_id => attributes[:second].to_i,
                                :third_id => attributes[:third].to_i)
```

And got this error, even though it was working before:

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute: first_id):
  app/controllers/api/v1/classroom_controller.rb:30:in `create'
```

I would like to get it working with first_or_create, but the second way would be an ok starting point

Answer (score 0):

If you're testing this, you'd need to boil it down even further:

```
@classroom = @user.classrooms.create(first_id: "1",second_id: "2", third_id: "3")
```

This will show whether the problem is with your variables or your tables. Your error reveals that your `Classroom` model doesn't recognize the `first_id` attribute. This suggests you don't have a `first_id` column in your `classrooms` db

In your rails Console, you should do this:

```
Classroom.column_names
#-> outputs column names
```

If this returns the column names with `first_id` etc, it's a problem with your associations. But I imagine you don't have the `first_id`, `second_id` or `third_id` columns set up

Comment: So I definitely have a first_id:, I checked with Classroom.column_names. The weird thing is that the classrooms were working before I added the has_many: and belong_to:. How would I fix an associations problem.